# how to catch the data from drop down list and view the result in a new blank target page?

Tags: php

this is the drop down code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>STUDENT REPORT</title>
    </head>


    <form action="" target="_blank" method=POST>

    <p align ='center'>
    <b> Please choose the reports you want to view .</b><br><br>
```

REPORTS :

```
    <select name='reportstud'>
        <option value="" selected> -----</option>
        <option value ="palcementconfirmation">PLACEMENT CONFIRMATION </option>
        <option value ="reportdutydetails">REPORT DUTY DETAILS </option>
        <option value ="feedback">ASSESSMENT/ FEEDBACK </option>
    </select>
     <p align ='center'> <br><br>
    <input type='submit' name='hit' value ='VIEW'>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

for example i want to view the data of placement from a page call placementconfirmation.php. how do i link to the page by only select the placement confirmation from the drop down?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: just use form method="post" and action="where ypu want to rediect url"  to access those values you can use $_POST['name']

Comment: u can easily done with jquery

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to do this or you can use simple form submit which you are trying to do.

where every you are posting your form process it there and send it to desired page like below

```
$report  = $_POST['reportstud'];
// do all your stuff here
if($report == 'palcementconfirmation'){
 header("Location: placementconfirmation.php?report=$report");
}
```

This will redirect you to the desired page with your selected value.

Comment: do i put this code in the form page or the targeted page (which is the placementconfirmation.php)?

Comment: Where you will process your form

Answer (score 0):

We can update form action on select change event. So if we give the form id with `reportForm` value:

```
<form action="" target="_blank" method="POST" id="reportForm">
...
```

Then we can catch select tag change event:

```
<select name='reportstud' onchange="document.getElementById('reportForm').setAttribute('action',this.value+'.php')">
...
```

Also here you could write full path in options value attribute:

```
<option value ="palcementconfirmation.php">PLACEMENT CONFIRMATION </option>
```

and on change event use just value: `...setAttribute('action',this.value)`

or leave it as it is.

Answer (score -1):

First You need to add an action to the form that maps to the blank view you are talking about , and depending on the form method the php page should have something like this:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['reportstud'];

?>
```

This is what i suggest ! i haven't tried it , so let me know what happens ;)

Regards